# Strange terminal behavior: 'j' key not working in urxvt

Tags: terminal, keyboard, openbsd, rxvt

For some bizarre reason my 'j' key stopped working properly. Every time I hit the key, it prints "true". If I type 'jake', the terminal prints:

```
 >>trueake
```

I don't know what lead to this. I guess it was after I installed something. I've tried rebooting, and did not work. How can I fix this?

CTRL-j also prints 'true'.

SHIFT-j works fine.

Xterm works fine.

I'm currently using OpenBSD 4.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this (I don't know if it's the only one) is to define a macro in Rxvt. Look through your X resources for a line like

```
Rxvt.keysym.j: true
```

This could be in your own file (usually `~/.Xresources`) or in a system file. Run `appres Rxvt` to see what resources rxvt is using. If the culprit turns out to be a buggy system file that you don't want to change, I think you can override it by putting a contrary definition in your own resource file:

```
Rxvt.keysym.j: builtin:
```